# Reload Bootstrap customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ it is possible to create and download a custom Bootstrap configuration. Included in the download is a file called config.json

Is it possible to use that file somehow to refill the values and tweak your custom bootstrap configuration?

If not, does someone know why that file is included?

Comment: do you mean your CSS or JS?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in recreating the custom bootstrap but with a few different css values.

Comment: well! you could "easily" change the values using a text editor with the find and replace option. It is not possible yet to have a UI for custom coloring.

Comment: Find-and-replace could replace individual color codes if you knew what they were.  But there are numerous places within the Bootstrap customization interface that lighten or darken various colors.  So understanding all the various shades that need to be changed, and exactly what color codes resulted from the lightening and darkening, is not an easy task.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's possible to reload and edit your configuration:

- download your custom bootstrap archive
- go to https://gist.github.com
- put content from your *config.json* file
- name the new gist **config.json**
- publish the gist (anonymously or under your name)
- save the gist number - the number in the gist url
- open bootstrap customizer (http://getbootstrap.com/customize) or your local one
- add the gist number to the url "?id=your_gist_number"

Voila! Configuration is reloaded.

Comment: It would be great if this works, but I can't get it to do so - the Bootstrap customizer ignores the id I supply it with. Can you share an example of a config.json gist that this works for?

Comment: I was wrong - this does work. Either it had problems fetching my gist initially, or I didn't notice that it can take a second for the form to update: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=8522849 using this gist: https://gist.github.com/philgyford/8522849

Comment: Good to note that if you are using Firefox and don't get a download for some reason it is because the form seems to be broken with the latest Firefox as of writing this (about v33). Switching to Chrome works

Answer (score 6):

[As of Bootstrap v3.2.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13790), you'll be able to load your existing `config.json` settings into the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) using drag-and-drop or a filepicker.

Comment: Off the top of your head, can the config.json be used with LESS too?

Comment: @Christina I mean, it includes all the LESS variable settings and LESS file exclusions. There's nothing built-in to make it work with Grunt, but you could easily take a `config.json` and write a little script to output a corresponding `variables.less`.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down to the end of the config.json file, the latest entry is "customizeUrl" along with the customization url on bootsrtap website. Eg:

```
"collapse.js",
"scrollspy.js",
"transition.js"
],
"customizerUrl": "http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=eaaea96b66287112b6c7"
}
```