# Twitter Bootstraps config.json - what does it do?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to find a way to only include specific bootstrap sections (css or js) but so far I just write a list down of what I am using, then tick those boxes on their customiser page.

However I noticed a `config.json` file that gets downloaded in the zip file, what does it do? I currently use `bower` as my asset package manager and `gulp` as my asset pipeline. But I don't think a `config.json` is relevant to them?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384330/reload-bootstrap-customization

Comment: the world worst documentation ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config.json file can be used with the full master download from github to config your build with grunt.

[edit]
Folks asked for more details: Bootstrap uses grunt, a JavaScript focused build utility similar to Java's Ant, that can build projects and executed automated tasks.  The grunt build could theoretically read the config.json file and modify its build to meet some specific tasks you need through changing the default config.json file and adding to, or subtracting from, the specific settings it contains.

Disclosure: I don't personally use grunt.js, but I have much respect for its creator, Ben.  I should probably learn how to use this tool.

Comment: Thank you, although I'd prefer more detail in the answer in future as accepting such a small answer seems... odd.

Comment: Can we have some elaboration on this? I would also like to build locally using the config.json, I have full master just want to know the location of the config.json before I start the build.

Answer (score 7):

The `config.json` file that is downloaded is nothing but a reminder of what your settings were when you downloaded. I would assume there will be some future functionality that would allow you to upload that file in to the website and reproduce the customized settings, but that feature doesn't currently exist, as far as I can tell.

If you are using bower, I would suggest using it to download Bootstrap for you. You can then use a LESS file to pull in the CSS features you want, and compile it using gulp/grunt in to your public asset directory. You can also use gulp/grunt to copy over the individual JS files you want in to a single file in that same asset directory.

Comment: Although this is a rather late reply (apologies), I would accept your answer due to the detail, but I strings28 in this case is correct (although lacking the detail you provided). Thanks though!

Comment: The future is really soon now. [As of Bootstrap v3.2.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13790), you'll be able to load your existing `config.json` settings into the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) using drag-and-drop or a filepicker.

Answer (score 4):

config.json stores the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) settings you used for your custom Bootstrap build.

You can reload those settings into the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) using the file upload at the top of the page, as of Bootstrap v3.3.0.

You can also alternatively extract the LESS variable values from the JSON and compile Bootstrap manually using those values, if you have a LESS compiler installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

This post might be old, but thought to update with what i have done.

### Issue

I have done some customization from `http://getbootstrap.com/customize/` which inturn provided `config.json` file. It would have been handy if `variables.less` files was also generated.

### Solution

For this reason i quickly setup a nodejs program to generate `variables.less` from `config.json`
https://github.com/tomalex0/bootstrap-config-to-variable

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the .json file, there's a link that will reload your settings in getbootstrap.com:

```
"customizerUrl": "http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id={random_id}"
```

Not sure how long the URL will be valid for, though.