# Use the Bootstrap config.json file with Bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

I used the Bootstrap customizer tool: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
It generates a `config.json` file that I reuse whenever I need to make changes.

I use Bower to handle all my dependencies, except Bootstrap, because I need my customized version.

Is there a way I can tell Bower to use my `config.json` file to generate the CSS?

The chosen answer to this question seems to state that it is actually possible, but it doesn't give much details and I couldn't find anything else about that anywhere: [Twitter Bootstraps config.json - what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433655/twitter-bootstraps-config-json-what-does-it-do)

I also found this package that lets you customize Bootstrap using your own LESS files, but that's not what I did, and it doesn't seem to use the `config.json` file: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-customize-bootstrap

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of my problem too.. this is making me crazy... No enough documentation what to do next after you get config.json in Bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bower to install bootstrap-sass-official or the less version if you want
and as stated here
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass

You can import bootstrap-custom and comment out the components that you don't need.

I had the same issue like you, this is what my bootstrap-custom.scss file looks like

```
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
...
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
```

And in my default.scss file i've put

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

And then compile!

***Ps: i wanted to point out the link in a comment but need 50 reputation point :(***