# Bootstrap config.json - What to do next?

Tags: css, json, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know what to do next after you compile and get config.json in Bootstrap?

> Any idea how to use it to update my current bootstrap.css?? or how to generate a css from it?? This is making me crazy, no enough documentation in Bootstrap about this..
>
> I found this link: [Twitter Bootstraps config.json - what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433655/twitter-bootstraps-config-json-what-does-it-do)

But the answer in there doesn't answer my questions. I'd really prefer more detailed answer. Thanks..^^

Comment: the config.json file is just here to know what a the default config, if you want to modify bootstrap, you have to modify the less or saas file and compile them

Answer (score 2):

config.json stores the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) settings you used for your custom Bootstrap build.

You can reload those settings into the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) using the file upload at the top of the page.

You can also alternatively extract the LESS variable values from the JSON and compile Bootstrap manually using those values, if you have a LESS compiler installed locally.

Comment: where is the documentation of this process ? why does one need a web config if he had installed node npm and grunt ?