# How to use the Bootstrap config.json file?

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

i saw you mentioning that you use the Bootstrap config.json file here: [Use the Bootstrap config.json file with Bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354163/use-the-bootstrap-config-json-file-with-bower)

I would like to know how i can use that file to furthur tweak my already customized version?

I'm just getting started with programming so please be forgiving if this is basic.
Thanks

Comment: What code?
I just want to use my config.json file to furthur edit my Bootstrap configuration. Since there is no way to do that on the 'Customize' section of the site, all i'd like to know is how do i use that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25942045/3342739

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload Bootstrap customization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384330/reload-bootstrap-customization)

Comment: Upvoted the question because I feel this question is useful and wanted to thank you for asking that. Plus when you said, `just getting started with programming...please be forgiving`, well, I felt like encouraging a beginner like you for getting rid of the stigma/hesitation and finding the confidence to ask. You never know, you could be helping many by asking this. This was the very purpose of stackexchange community.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and fill the form with your custom settings.
- At the bottom of the page, click on "Compile and Download". You will get a bootstrap.zip file containing all the customized files and a `config.json` file.
- Insert the files you need in your project
- If you need to regenerate the customized files, go to https://gist.github.com/ and create a new gist containing the content of the `config.json` file
- Get the unique id of the gist in its URL
- Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=GISTID (replace GISTID with the id of the gist you just created)
- The form will be pre-filled with your previous settings. Don't forget to update your gist with the new `config.json` file for future use.

Comment: Is there any way to get your customized bootstrap through bower? That's what I use to manage all my dependencies. It would be great if somehow when you type `bower install bootstrap` you could actually somehow pass along your `config.json` file or point to your gist or something. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I am interested to the same but for Yarn